# It's not the size of your magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, molecular-dynamics

Growing up I've seen magnets on the fridge to the cows stomach and the latest that I know of, neodymium. On a molecular level what makes some magnetic material stronger and last longer than others?
[image]

Comment: *"magnets on the fridge from the cows stomach"*...what? Also, what is the picture supposed to add?

Comment: @ACuriousMind http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_disease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The microscopic origin of magnetism is difficult to understand without quantum physics. I will explain the essential quantum physics at the end but first I want to answer your question. The strength of a magnet is determined by how electrons interact in a material. It is electrons that ultimately lead to the magnetism you see in a fridge magnet. The physics of many electrons all interacting with each other in materials goes by the name of "strongly correlated materials" and is a very hot topic of research which includes magnetism, high-temperature superconductivity, and many more exotic phenomena.

The effects responsible for magnetism cannot be understood in terms of classical physics. The essential piece of quantum physics necessary for understanding magnetism is the Pauli exclusion principle. This principle says that two electrons with the same spin cannot be at the same position. Spin is a very confusing concept at first. In essence every electron has a tiny magnet attached. The confusing part is that the magnet is not like ordinary magnets you have played with. It is a quantum magnet. You cannot ask which way the magnet is pointing, you can only ask if it is pointing up or down. The answer to this question will be +1/2 if it is pointing up and -1/2 if it is pointing down, and there is no other answer you can get, only +1/2 and -1/2. This is very confusing if you have not seen it before but bare with me and just think of an electron as having an extra bit of information and this information takes only two values.

Now suppose we have two atoms sitting close to each other and there are two electrons on these two atoms, then there are four possibilities for how the electrons can be arranged. In state one both electrons are on the same atom, but then their spins have to be opposite because of the exclusion principle. In state two they are both on the other atom and again they have to have opposite spin. In state three they are on different atoms with opposite spin. Finally in state four they are on different atoms and have the same spin. We know that like charges repel each other so state one and state two are not good states for the electrons to be in. It seems like state three and state four are both good states for the electrons to be in, but it turns out state three is better for the electrons. This is because electrons like to move around. If they are stuck on one atom then there is a big cost in kinetic energy. If we choose state four then it is hard for the electrons to move around. This is because the electrons have to flip there spins before they can move to the other atom (remember this is because of the Pauli exclusion principle). In state three the electrons free to move around and they do not start out on the same atom so they are very happy.

Unfortunately we have found that the electrons in this system prefer to have opposite spins. We have just discovered an antiferromagnet. You are interested in ferromagnets where electrons all have the same spin. Once you get enough of these tiny spins pointing in the same direction the effect becomes strong enough that you can stick it to your fridge. Fortunately the same logic that I just used to find antiferromagnetism leads to to ferromagnetism in some much more complicated systems. There are many other mechanisms that can lead to ferromagnetism besides what I have just described. They all go by the name of exchange mechanism. The essential pieces that we needed are:

1) Pauli exclusion principle

2) Electrons interacting (don't like to be on the same site)

The Pauli exclusion principle will be the same in every magnet but it is very important for magnetism. The interaction part is what changes from material to material. This can be changed by changing the atoms in the material or by changing how the atoms are laid out (the crystal structure).

Answer (score 1):

A less sophisticated but perhaps more approachable answer is this:

Permanent magnetism of a material originates from charged particles (electrons in most cases) rotating in the material. When a charge particle accelerates, it creates a magnetic field, if it is rotating around a center, then its centripetal acceleration will create a magnetic field that is partially linear at the poles, like this:
[image]

In permanent magnetic material a **majority** of particles are rotating in the same direction, so their the magnetic fields add up and give the object as a whole a magnetic field.

In weakly magnetic material, the coherently rotating "majority" of the charges are a small fraction of all rotating charges, whereas in strong magnets, the "majority" involves much more rotating charges and thus a stronger overall magnetic field.